# d3.js: can I encapsulate arc definitions in a function?

Tags: d3.js

I'm starting with d3.js, I have a simple example that constructs a circle out of 4 arcs.

The key piece of d3 code generates the arcs like so:

```
var data = [ "#003399", "#0099CC", "#0099FF", "#0000FF"];
...
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(rd*3)
        .outerRadius(rd*4)
        .startAngle(function(d,i) { return i*ad; })
        .endAngle(function(d,i) { return (i+1)*ad; }))
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return d; })
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 +"," + w/2 + ")");
```

The [complete example](http://jsfiddle.net/doshigatai/3cMpj/) is on JSFiddle

Now I'd like to put the d3.svg.arc() call in a function because I'd like to generate many more sections) so it looks like this:

```
var mkarc = function (d, i) {
    return d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(rd * 3)
    .outerRadius(rd * 4)
    .startAngle(i * ad)
    .endAngle((i + 1) * ad);
}
```

and then attr("d", d3.svg.arc()... ) becomes just attr("d", mkarc)

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", mkarc)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + w / 2 + ")");
```

But this generates a "Parsing problem" setting the attribute.  I've seen a few of these in stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I haven't been able to puzzle out the root problem.

Here's a [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doshigatai/3cMpj/7/) with the alternate approach that does not work.

Fixes, and some hint as to the principles behind them would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple mistake -- before, you were calling the function that `d3.svg.arc()` returns, now you're calling a function that *returns the function `d3.svg.arc()`*. That is, you return an unevaluated function to `mkarc`. All you need to do is apply the arc generator you've made to the `d` argument and you're fine:

```
var mkarc = function (d, i) {
  return d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(rd * 3)
    .outerRadius(rd * 4)
    .startAngle(i * ad)
    .endAngle((i + 1) * ad)(d);
}
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cMpj/9/).

Comment: Thanks, that works! I was proud of myself for just remembering I could return an function from a function.  Reminds me a little bit of trying to keep track pointers with two and three levels of indirection.